# Parsing xml attributes with embedded double-quotes in their values using XMLDocument object

Tags: c#, xml, regex

This is a web project.
I receive a partial html string from an external source.  Using XMLDocument to parse it works well except when it encounters an attribute with embedded quotes such as the "style" attribute below.

```
<span id="someId" style="font-family:"Calibri", Sans-Serif;">Some Text</span>
```

It seems as though (but I could be wrong) that LoadXml() thinks that the double-quote before Calibri ends the style attribute and that Calibri is another "token" (token is the term I get in the error message).

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(<the html string above, properly escaped>); // <--- here is where I get the error message below

"'Calibri' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 18."
```

I can use Regex to replace the inner quotes but it will be rather ugly.  And, I may well end up doing it!

I thought perhaps HtmlAgilityPack would help, but I couldn't find good documentation on it and I would rather avoid 3rd party libraries with sparse documentation.

Is there a way to make LoadXml() accept it (and, subsequently, have the Attributes collection parse it correctly)?  I don't have much hope for that, but I am throwing it out there anyways.  Or should I be using another class altogether other than XmlDocument?  I am open to using a 3rd party library with good documentation.

Comment: As a side note you should be using XDocument instead of XmlDocument as it is deprecated as of .NET 3.5

Comment: You would really be better off getting your third party to send you valid XML. They may not even be aware they are sending invalid XML - it might simply be a bug in their code, or they may not understand XML. If you can educate them, they will be a better business partner for you.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: No, XmlDocument isn't deprecated. It's worth using XDocument simply because it's a better API, but XmlDocument itself is still fine.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misplaced knowledge. Someone told me that awhile ago guess I could have checked. :) Cheers.

Comment: Ah...thank you Cubicle Jockey.  I didn't know that it was deprecated.

Comment: OK.  I guess I should probably use XDocument instead.  But I am still left with embedded double quotes, which, by the way, are parsed and displayed fine by the browser.  I just have many more edits to the string before I render it and that is why I need to get over this problem

Comment: @shakyjake: I agree with John Saunders: fundamentally this is invalid XML, and you should get the producer to fix it. It's not hard to produce valid XML, and I'd be very nervous of anyone who failed to do it :(

Comment: The fact that garbage is "displayed fine by the browser" is not much of a recommendation. Browsers are used to dealing with bad HTML - bad XML isn't that much of a stretch. And, even if it's "displayed" properly by the browser, I wonder if the browser has parsed it into the DOM in the way you would like.

Comment: I really want to emphasize that [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) has been a standard for well over a decade. Any company which cannot produce valid XML should probably not be in business. In any case, they should probably not be in business with _you_.

Comment: I agree that if the browser displays it, it is still not a recommendation.  I did not intend for it to be.  I am just stating it as an FYI.

Answer (score 5):

That data is invalid. An attribute quoted with double quotes cannot contain double quotes in the attribute value. An attribute quoted with single quotes cannot have single quotes in the value.

Valid:

```
<tag attr1="value with 'single' quotes" attr2='value with "double" quotes' />
```

Invalid:

```
<tag attr1="value with "double" quotes" attr2='value with 'single' quotes' />
```

Note that the invalid example can be made valid as follows:

```
<tag attr1="value with &quot;double&quot; quotes" attr2='value with &apos;single&apos; quotes' />
```

Comment: Possibly give an example with `&quot;` or `&apos;` for how quotes/apostrophes would be encoded within an attribute which uses the same character as the start/end?

Comment: It is not under my control.  As I said, I receive this from an external source.

Comment: @shakyjake: it's funny. I hear this all the time ("not under my control, external source"). But even way "back in the day", we had this thing called "edits". We would process input data from "external sources", maybe from magnetic tapes or punch cards, and the data would be required to pass certain tests, or "edits". The result of this process would be one tape (or maybe disk file) containing valid data, and an "edit report" telling the source about any invalid data. What has changed over the years such that you are now obligated to accept garbage data? Are you a slave?

Comment: I see... a slave!  "Back in the day"  I did all the things you mentioned.  But, this one is truly not under my control, nor can I persuade the source to change it.  I guess I am a slave!

Comment: @shakyjake: note that "slave" was a question, not a statement. Do all their files have this garbage in it? What happens if you just reject the garbage, then tell them why? I mean, if you tell them this is garbage, and the answer is, well, ok, but we won't fix the garbage, then that's one thing. Being afraid to tell them it's garbage is close to the other thing.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, "afraid?"  As far as any one here is concerned, and for whatever reason, I can't control it.  That's that!  Let's not continue this back-and-forth.  It is not productive.